# Triple of oriented similar triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $A_iB_iC_i, i = 1,2,3$, be similar triangles with the same orientation such that $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are collinear and $B_1, B_2, B_3$ are collinear. Does it follow that $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are collinear?

It seems intuitively true but I have no idea how to prove it, even with a bashy coordinate approach. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I can only say, sketch a figure. It follows almost trivially from the property of parallel lines.

Comment: @Allawonder  Are you sure?

Comment: @DesmondMiles The [first] two answers below bring up the question: Are $A_1, A_2, A_3$ sides or vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample with three right isosceles triangles.

[image]

and another with non-parallel lines and equilateral triangles.

[image]

Comment: "The statement "$A_iB_iC_i, i = 1,2,3$"  suggests that $ABC$ are the sides of a triangle and not the vertices.  This and the words "same orientation" and "collinear" suggest that sides $A$ and $B$ are parallel and overlap. It also suggests, only the right angle vertices are collinear.

Comment: I was told that ["collinear"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity) is meant for points, not sides.

Comment: The line segment of any side is defined by two points and these can be collinear with any other two points.

Comment: This leaves some room for ambiguity. Maybe OP can clarify which situation they were looking at. You'd be correct if $A_{1}$ is a side.

Answer (score 0):

If the sides $A$ and $B$ of any two or more right triangles are colinear, side $C$ will be parallel but not colinear unless they are identical. That is,

If they have the same orientation and are similar, e.g. $(3,4,5)\quad (6,8,10)\quad (9,12,15) ...$ all internal angles will be the same so, by Euclidean geometry, it follows that the sides with lengths $5, 10, 15 ...$ will be parallel. Sides-C will not be colinear unless they are identical but they will be parallel.

See if you can find his statements about lines intersecting parallel lines form equal angles if you want to get formal

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that corresponding sides will be parallel? I did some drawings and I think I got a counterexample.

Comment: @poetasis, what if your middle right triangle is flipped about $3k$ side. What follows?

Comment: @osmo5 Good point. That would ruin my argument about side-C being parallel but the OP says they have the same orientation. In any case, both your answer and mine support the idea that any side-or-vertex-C cannot be collinear.

Comment: That's right. The answer is still same. Probably there is duality between vertices and sides, but I don't know that much deep.